# JQuery Masonry and Infinite Scroll in Wordpress

Tags: php, jquery, css, infinite-scroll

I'm currently in the process of making a portfolio website for myself, using a modified version the ['Gridly'](http://www.eleventhemes.com/gridly-theme/) wordpress theme. [Here's the current website](http://www.finlaydownes.com/).

Right now I'm trying to implement the ['infinite scroll' plugin](http://www.infinite-scroll.com/), but I can't seem to get it to work.

I'm not sure if anyone here is familiar with this specific plugin, but just in case, the selectors that I'm using are:

```
Content Selector: #post-area
Navigation Selector: .view-older
Next Selector: .view-older a:first
Item Selector: .post
```

I can't really tell what code would be relevant to post here, but here is what the index.php contains:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

<?php if (have_posts()) : ?>
<div id="post-area">
<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?> 

<div id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
     <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { ?>
     <div class="gridly-image"><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail( 'summary-image' );  ?></a></div>
      <div class="gridly-category"><p><?php the_category(', ') ?></p></div>

      <?php } ?>
            <div class="gridly-copy"><h2><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
            <p class="gridly-date"><?php the_time(get_option('date_format')); ?>  </p>

<?php the_excerpt(); ?> 

           <p class="gridly-link"><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"></a></p>
     </div>
   </div> 



<?php endwhile; ?>
</div>
<?php else : ?>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php next_posts_link('<p class="view-older">View Older Entries</p>') ?>


<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

I've also set the behavior to Masonry/Isotope, and made sure the plugin is activated.

If anyone could help me solve this problem I'd hugely appreciate it. I'm (clearly) not a web developer, so please bear with me if any of this sounds silly.

Comment: The Chrome inspector reports that `Your nextSelector found no elements.`

Comment: Using the debug option, I've managed to determine that the 'next selector' is not finding any elements.

Comment: Beat me to it. ;)

I'm still not sure how to solve the problem, however.

Comment: I suspect I may have accidentally deleted an important piece of code while I was mucking around with the index.php. I'll restore a backup and see if that helps.

Comment: Nope, that wasn't it.

Comment: It seems like the code to add a 'view newer entries' link is completely missing. I'm not sure why.

Answer (score 2):

I did it! For the benefit of anyone who might encounter the same problem, this was how I solved it:

Firstly, for some reason this theme included a 'view older posts' function, but it didn't include a 'view newer posts' one. I solved this by copying

```
<?php next_posts_link('<p class="view-older">View Older Entries</p>') ?>
```

and both creaing a div around the link, and adding another line of code, so that it states

```
<div ="navigation>
<?php next_posts_link('<p class="view-older">View Older Entries</p>') ?>
<?php previous_posts_link('<p class="view-newer">View Newer Entries</p>') ?>
</div>
```

Next, I changed the infinite scroll selectors to

```
Content Selector: #post-area
Navigation Selector: #navigation
Next Selector: #navigation a:first
Item Selector: #post-area .post
```

Hopefully that will help if anyone else encounters a similar issue. :)

Answer (score 1):

Not really an answer, I'm afraid, but it's too long for a comment. Your link ends up a bit screwy in the HTML, with an `a` wrapped around a `p` (which, though technically 'legal' with your doctype, isn't a good idea).

```
<a href="http://www.finlaydownes.com/page/2/" ><p class="view-older">View Older Entries</p></a>
```

Not sure how `a:first` is meant to be targeted, or what it refers to.

Comment: Hello again! :) I just noticed that myself, not sure how to fix it yet but I'm working on it.